# Haskell evaluation synchronisation between threads

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm trying to understand how GHC Haskell synchronises the computation of "basic" values (i.e. not IORef, TVar, etc.) between threads. I have searched for information about this but haven't found anything clear.

Take the following example program:

```
import Control.Concurrent

expensiveFunction x = sum [1..x] -- Just an example

val = expensiveFunction 12345

thread1 = print val

thread2 = print val

main = do
    forkOS thread1
    forkOS thread2
```

I understand that the value val will initially be represented by an unevaluated closure. In order to print val, the program must first evaluate it. Once a toplevel binding has been evaluated it should not need to be evaluated again.

1. Is the representation for "val" even shared by separate threads?
2. If for some reason thread1 completes evaluation first, can it convey the final computed value to thread2 by swapping out the pointer? How would that be synchronised?
3. If thread1 is busy evaluating when thread2 wants the value, does thread2 wait for it to finish or do they both race to evaluate it first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In GHC-compiled programs, values go through three(-ish) phases of evaluation:

1. Thunk. This is where they start.
2. Black hole. When forced, a thunk is converted to a black hole and computation begins. Other threads that request the value of a black hole will instead add themselves to a notification list for when the black hole is updated. (Also, if the thunk itself tries to access the black hole, it will short-circuit to an exception instead of waiting forever.)
3. Evaluated. When the computation finishes, its last task is to update the black hole to a plain value (well, WHNF value, anyway).

The pointer that is getting updated during these phase transitions is shared with other threads and *not* protected from race conditions. This means that, very rarely, it is possible for two (or more) threads to both see a pointer in phase 1 and for both to execute the 1 -> 2 transition; in that case, both will evaluate the thunk, and the transition 2 -> 3 will also happen twice. Notably, though, the 1 -> 2 transition is typically much faster than the computation it is replacing (essentially just a memory access or two), in part exactly so that the race is difficult to trigger.

Because the language is pure, the racing threads will come to the same answer. So there is no semantic difficulty here. But in some rare cases, a little bit of work may be duplicated. It is very, very rare that the overhead of a lock on every 1 -> 2 transition would be better than this slight duplication. (If you find it is in your case, consider manually protecting the evaluation of whichever expensive thing is being shared!)

Corollary: great care must be taken with the unsafe `IO a -> a` family of functions; some guarantee synchronization of the evaluation of the resulting `a` and some don't. If your `IO a` action is not as pure as you promised it is, and a race causes it to be executed twice, all manner of strange heisenbugs can occur.